# Crash when focus on UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, crash, uitextfield

I have a UITextField which inside a UITableCell in a xib file
TableView dequeue the cell, try editing the text fieldon iOS 7, it work fine.
When I tested the app in iOS 8,  it crash the app and throw the exception below when touching (focus) on the textfield :

```
-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faacacbf110
```

The custom cell not override any UITableViewCell method and implement any method.
The textfield just a UITextField, not override anything.

Problem found in all tableview which contain this cell.
The textfield work fine when enable Secure Text Entry

Tessted:

iOS 7.1 (Simulator)
iOS 8.1.3 (iPhone 5 , Simulator)
iOS 8.3 beta (Simulator)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: Does the code crash on a device?  You could also try enabling zombies to see where memory is getting leaked: Edit your current scheme, then under the Diagnostics tab check "Enable Zombie objects".